# Which components to built remapping keyboard via USB in + out (remapped)

Tags: usb, signal-processing

I know that it's fairly easy to change the emulate keyboard and mouse by Arduino. But I'm quite specific about the goal I would like to achieve hence I would appreciate if you could advise me which components (Arduino compatible) I am going to need to have such a built:

Physical usb keyboard --> Arduino via usb IN --> keys remapping (for example pressing q will return ctrl+3 or more advanced action) --> Arduino USB OUT (which I can directly plug in to my computer and receive modified keyboard commands).

To sum up I  just want Arduino to work as intermediary.

Will simple Arduino Uno + USB shield do the work?

Thank you a lot for your support!

Comment: The Due might be cheaper than a leonardo+usbHost shield, but I guess you would need a female usb to male micro-usb adapter. In any case, can't this be done on the target computer a lot cheaper and easier?

Comment: The thing is I wanted it to be stand-alone and easily transferable across different devices (on which one unfortunately cannot install any developer tools)

Comment: you should look into the maximum bandwidth a keyboard needs and then do some tests to see how much latency the arduino adds processing that much data. If its acceptable, you should be good to go (I imagine this will be the case). Oh and make sure whatever you buy has at least 1 usb host port, emphasis on host.

Comment: Thank you BrettAM. Yes, as you have guessed latency is not going to be an issue as even up to 500ms is totally ok as device is not going to be a prank or hidden hack, just to make my life easier with plenty of repeatable shortcut sequences. I'm aware of USB host requirement. After some research I learned that this will be much easier with arduino brother - Teensy. Plenty of interesting and easy to do projects on their website here --> http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/projects.html